# send complete image object with POST

Tags: php, jquery, gif

I'm trying to get this code.

```
<?php
$image = $_POST['image'];     
$image = base64_decode($image);    
$name = hash('md5', time()) . '.gif';    
file_put_contents($name, $image);
echo '{"name": "' . $name . '"}';
```

to work with this..

```
$('#save').click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'images/save.php',
         method: 'POST',
         data: {
             image: b64
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
             var a = $('<a />').attr('href', "images/" + data.name).html('permalink');
             $('#url').append(a);
         },
         error: function(err) {
             console.log(err);
         }
     });
 });
```

I was told to do this, but I am kind of stuck on what it means.

send complete image object with POST to this script, image will be saved on your disk and JSON response wit image name will be return.

Comment: Looks ok to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Hmmm. I was told it would enable it the image to save to the /images folder. I tried setting the folder to 755 and even 777 and still nothing. I think I'm missing something, but not 100% sure. This script turns Webcam into gif image. Which all works fine except for this save feature. All I'm trying to do is get it to save to the images folder on the server, so I can later go back and possibly have a seperate page for most recent made gifs.

Comment: .gif for pictures ? your webcam is generating gif images ???

Comment: Yes. Which is the script. I dunno if I am allowed links here but take a quick look. buddystack.com/camtest

Comment: lol... www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIc-KSs-3xc

Comment: It already makes it a gif, it just doesnt save on the server. That's all I'm trying to figure out.